# Meteor: show something on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I got a problem in Meteor.

I want to show and hide a part of a template when I click a button (Like revealing a answer to a question e.g).

The problem is that this part of the template is created dynamically and I just want to reveal the answer that is correlated to the button. so you cant just have a template helper, that needs to return "true" to show the answer, because then on a button click every answer is revealed.

```
    <template name="cardList">
      {{#each card}}
        <div class="card">
          <h3>{{frontsideText}}</h3>
          <p class="answer">{{backsideText}}</p>
          <button class="btn btn-danger deleteButton">delete</button> 
          <button class="btn btn-default showButton">show Answer</button> 
        </div>
      {{/each}}
    </template>
```

I tried it with jQuery, which worked kind of. something like:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  $(".answer").hide();
}

Template.cardList.events({
"click .showButton": function(event) {
  $(event.target).prevAll(".answer").first().show();
}
```

But this doesnt work, because then every new added Question or whatever has the answer revealed, because they are just hidden on startup. I guess I need to put the hide() function somewhere else, but I dont know where.

And is there a way to solve this problem with just Meteor and no jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous ways to do this, here are two:

**1. Using meteor**
You could make a new template called *card*, put it in the {{#each card}} and use the following event. This will hide the answer whenever a new card is rendered.

```js
Template.card.rendered = function(){
    this.$("p.answer").hide();
};
```

**2. Changing your snippet to work with JQuery**
The problem is you're hiding your element the wrong way. You shouldn't hide it with js, but with css. That way it's hidden by default.

```css
.card p.answer{
  display: none;  
}
```

Either way would make your click event code work. Personally I'd combine the options I suggested: Make a template for the cards (it's cleaner/easier to work on nicely contained templates) and adjust the css so it is hidden by default.

Let me know if you have any other questions