# How to show a form on click of a dynamically generated each block in meteor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, meteor

How can I show a form on click of a dynamically generated button on each block of the code in meteor?

```
<div id="wCard">

                {{#each workflow}}
                <div class="pheader">
                     <h2>{{project}}</h2>
                     <hr width="90%">
                </div>
                     <br>
                 <div class="workflowcard">
                 <div class="module-card">
                   <div>
                    <div class="card-header wfmodule">{{workflowTitle}}</div>
                    <div class="assigned-tag">Assigned To:</div>
                    <div class="assigned-to">{{team}}<hr></div>
                    <div class="actions">No Actions Created</div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        due date
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="actionBtn"><button class="btn-wf stage-blue-wf button-x-small-wf" id="newAction">New Action</button></div>

            </div>
                {{/each}}

        </div>
```

This the card dynamically generating when I submit a form. In this card I have a new action button, when I click on new action button of dynamically generated card it should display another form.

Comment: do you have any sample code on which are you working ?

Comment: If I am right you want to display a form on button click for each block ?

Comment: yes. how can we do that?

Comment: Maybe if you would read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370), you would have a higher chance to get useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Template helpers and jquery for this.

Example code: 
main.html

```
<template name="test">
     <div id="form1" class="hidden">
        Form Stuff
     </div>

     <button id="click_button">Click to Show form</button>
```

In javascript file- main.js

```
Template.test.events({
   "click #click_button" : function() {
         $( "#form1" ).removeClass( "hidden");
}
```

The `class="hidden"` will work when you have bootstrap package (`twbs:bootstrap`) added.

Comment: Will it work for dynamically generated card? beacuse the button is there inside the crd.

Comment: Yes it will. Just be careful with the class and id selectors.

Comment: Hey Ankit thank you so much. It's working fine. thanks again.Can I ask you If I stuck at some where in my coding?

Comment: Sure. If this answer helped, can you please mark my answer as accepted. It's the 'tick' mark that you will see beside this answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28341943/meteor-show-something-on-button-click - I want the same like in the the link and It's working fine.I want to display the hide content on click of a button. How do I write a js to display the template data. Have u understood my question??

Comment: you can use `.hide()` and `.show()` JQuery functions to do that.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. the hide data is there inside another template. so I want to display the hide template on click of the button.