# show hidden part of the dynamic card on button click in meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, meteor

I have created a card dynamically and hide some part of the content by taking it in another template and called on each block and it's working fine. Now how to display the hidden part on button click?

Here I am attaching my code.

```
  <div id="newActionCard">
        {{#each newaction}}
                     <div class="workflowcard">
                     <div class="module-card">

                         <div class="  assigned-team">{{team}}</div>
                        <div class=" newaction-name">{{action_title}}</div><hr>
                        <div class="description">{{description}}</div>
                        <div class=" due-on">Due on:{{d_date}}</div><hr>
                        <div class="subcontent">
                       <div class="action"> {{actioncardsubcontent}} </div>
                       </div>
                       </div>



            <div class="btn-box newaction">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="cancelsub">New Action</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="createbtnsub">Show Options</button>
        </div>
                </div>

                    {{/each}}
            </div>




    </template>

<template name="actioncardsubcontent">
    <div class="subcontent">
             <div class="modulepath">{{module_list}}</div>
            <div class="linkto">Linked To: {{link}}</div>
             <div class="description">{{description}}</div>
    </div>
</template>
```

and JS is:

```
Template.workflow.events({
    "click .actionBtn":function(){

        $('#createAction').show();
    },

   "click #createbtnsub" : function() {
         $( ".subcontent" ).show();
        $('#createbtnsub').hide();
       $('#cancelsub').hide();
}


});

Template.actioncardsubcontent.rendered = function(){
    this.$(".subcontent").hide();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are including the template incorrectly. It should be `{{> actioncardsubcontent}}`
2. To link up with a button to hide/show, follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137186/show-form-on-click-of-dynamically-generated-each-block-in-the-meteor/39138644#39138644)
3. Please share the js script as well with helpers and events if the above steps don't solve the issue.

Comment: now it is showing the hidden part but it is working for all cards instead of 1 card. Means when I click on particular card it should display the hidden part. How to fix that? I added my js as well. And please don't mind I am very new to meteor.

Comment: `<div class="subclass" id="{{id}}">
   <div class="action"> {{actioncardsubcontent}} </div>
</div>`

operate upon that id and only will show/close.

Comment: Is JS:

Replace: `$( ".subcontent" ).show();` with `var id='#'+this._id;`
`($(id).show();`

Comment: Can you help me please.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use some html tags to hide content...and ...get back them by clicking.The tags are

```
<details>
<summary>Card</summary>
<p>content 1</p>
<p>content 2</p>
</details>
```

Put your details after the summary tag. Onclicking the Card (summary) you can get the hidden content of the card.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to apply another each loop for the other template.

```
<template name="actioncardsubcontent">
    <div class="subcontent">
             {{#each newaction}}
             <div class="modulepath">{{module_list}}</div>
            <div class="linkto">Linked To: {{link}}</div>
             <div class="description">{{description}}</div>
            {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>
```